# Why this XML parsing Ruby code runs slower with GC disabled?

Tags: ruby, performance, garbage-collection

I've got a piece of code parsing 500 MB XML file using `libxml-ruby` gem. What is surprising to me, this code runs **slower** with GC **disabled**, which seems counter-intuitive. What might be the reason? I've go plenty of memory available and the system is not swapping.

```
require 'xml'

#GC.disable

@reader = XML::Reader.file('books.xml', :options => XML::Parser::Options::NOBLANKS)

@reader.read 
@reader.read

while @reader.name == 'book'
  book_id = @reader.get_attribute('id')
  @reader.read

  until @reader.name == 'book' && @reader.node_type == XML::Reader::TYPE_END_ELEMENT
    case @reader.name
    when 'author'
      author = @reader.read_string
    when 'title'
      title = @reader.read_string
    when 'genre'
      genre = @reader.read_string
    when 'price'
      price = @reader.read_string
    when 'publish_date'
      publish_date = @reader.read_string
    when 'description'
      description = @reader.read_string
    end
    @reader.next
  end

  @reader.read      

end
@reader.close
```

Here are the results I got:

```
ruby     gc on   gc off
2.2.0    16.93s  18.81s
2.1.5    16.22s  18.58s
2.0.0    17.63s  17.99s
```

Why disable the garbage collector? I've read in [Ruby Performance Optimization](https://pragprog.com/book/adrpo/ruby-performance-optimization) book that Ruby is slow mostly because programmers don't think about memory consumption, which makes garbage collector use a lot of execution time. Thus turning off the GC should instantly speed things up (at the cost of memory usage of course), as long as the system is not swapping.

I wanted to see if my XML parsing module can be improved, so I started experimenting with it by disabling the GC, which brought me to this problem. I expected a significant speed-up with GC disabled, but instead I got the opposite. I know that differences are not huge, but still this is strange to me.

`libxml-ruby` gem uses a native C `LibXML` implementation under the hood - can it be the reason?

The file that I used is manually multiplicated `books.xml` sample downloaded from some Microsoft documentation:

```
<catalog>
 <book id="bk101">
  <author>John Doe</author>
  <title>XML for dummies</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>Some description</description>
 </book>
 ....
</catalog>
```

My setup: OS X Yosemite, Intel Core i5 2.6 GHz, 16GB of RAM.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: @engineersmnky if he is asking how to make it faster, it belongs here, not on code review.  If he wants help with all of it, it should go there.

Comment: @engineersmnky "What might be the reason? I've go plenty of memory available and the system is not swapping."

Comment: @engineersmnky See the bit further below, which says "Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?". OP does not want that sort of feedback.

Comment: @engineersmnky Contrary to what is often stated in Code Review-migration-suggestions, **specific** code improvements are absolutely On-Topic for Stack Overflow. In any case, as best I can tell, the OP is \*not\* asking for a performance tune-up, but asking a specific question about why the Garbage Collector is exhibiting behaviour that is contrary to expectations in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting the operating system - you've disabled GC in your MRI process but you have no control over the linux/unix kernel and how it allocates memory to your MRI application.

In fact, I believe that by disabling GC you have significantly hamstrung the behaviour of your application, making it likely that your program will need to continuously request more RAM from the kernel.  This will likely involve some form of overhead in the kernel as it allocates swap or memory to you.

Your source data is a 500 mb xml file that you are reading, node by node, into your MRI program's memory footprint.  It's likely your MRI process consumes several GB of data by the time it is done processing; and none of the values in your main reading block are discarded after each iteration -  they simply hang around in memory, and are only finally cleaned up when your application exits and the memory is handed back to the operating system.

GC is in place to manage this; it is intended to prevent your application from requesting additional memory from the kernel unless it absolutely needs it, and to allow your application to run "well enough" within the memory allocated to it within reason.

So I'm not honestly surprised you see a slowdown with GC disabled.  What would be telling is the load average and swap usage of your box during your benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion with OS allocation overhead. I'll do some additional benchmarks with that in mind.

Comment: Presumably you're right. I can see that process is constantly allocating more and more memory in little increments. To prove your point I looked for a way to preallocate big amount of memory at the beginning (like `-Xmx` switch in Java), so that it wouldn't be necessary to spend any time on that during the execution. But apparently it's not possible in Ruby.